# Xcode run script during build

Tags: c++, xcode, sqlite

I'm working on a project which has a SQLite database, built by running "sqlite3 [db filename] < [schema filename]" from the Terminal on Mac OS X.  I'd like to learn more about the projects system in Xcode, and ideally get it to run this Terminal command automatically when I build the project, additionally copying the created database into the output directory of the C++ project.  I've been able to do similar things with Visual Studio before, and I get the impression from the options presented that I can do the same thing in Xcode.

I've added an external build target with the database schema files inside it (so they get source controlled too) and at first it was running with errors that too many arguments were being passed.  However, I put single quotes around the arguments and now it runs.  But I don't see any output.  The file is not generated in the directory I set and I can't find it anywhere else.  I was wondering if it took the single quotes as a single argument to sqlite3, but I can't find anything named that either.

I keep finding tutorials such as this one: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/precompilation-run-script-in-xcode-4 but it appears that Xcode has changed since they were written and I'm having no luck on 5.0.1.  I can't seem to get it to run shell scripts, (hopeful for a workaround) can't find the output of what appear to be successfully run commands, and cannot add Aggregate/External Build Tool projects to the dependencies of my code project, so even if I had it working, it would not rebuild the database with the source code.

I'm more after an outline of the best way to do this in 5.0.1, because I suspect my entire approach may be wrong here.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you search?  I am 100% certain there are answers relating to running scripts during builds on SO.

Comment: I did look, but I had no luck reproducing their results and they seemed to be written for Xcode 4.  I've just managed to get it running a makefile.  Just need to sort out the dependency from the code project.  Was wondering if my entire approach was incorrect.  Thank you for reading.

Comment: Using a makefile sounds wrong; everything you can do with `make` can be done with `Xcode`.  There isn't a great deal of difference between using build scripts in Xcode 4 and Xcode 5, so just use those answers you find.

Comment: I tried following them, but I keep hitting instructions telling me to choose options I just do not have.  All the screenshots show completely different menus to those I have in 5.0.1.  I'm just interested to know the approach I should be using or if I'm using completely the wrong tools or something.